# Long strings in pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I want to be able to use a string that is quite long (not longer then 100000 signs).
As far as I know a typical string variable can cotain only up to 256 chars.
Is there a way to store such a long string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old-style (Turbo Pascal, or Delphi 1) strings, now known as `ShortString`, are limited to 255 characters (byte 0 was reserved for the string length). This appears to still be the default in FreePascal (according to @MarcovandeVoort's comment below). Keep reading, though, until you get to the discussion and code sample for `AnsiString` below. :-)

Currently, most other dialects of Pascal I'm aware of default to either `AnsiString` (long strings of single byte characters) or `UnicodeString` (long strings of multi-byte characters). Neither of those are limited to 255 characters.

The current versions of Delphi defaults to `UnicodeString` as the default type, so declaring a `string` variable is in fact a long `UnicodeString`. There is no practical upper limit to the string length:

```
var
  Test: string;  // Declare a new Unicode string
begin
  SetLength(Test, 100000);   // Initialize it to hold 100000 characters
  Test := StringOfChar('X', 100000);  // Fill it with 100000 'X' characters
end;
```

If you want to force single-byte characters (but not be limited to 255 character strings), use `AnsiString` (which can set as the default `string` type in FreePascal if you use the `{$H+}` compiler directive - thanks @MarcovandeVoort):

```
var
  Test: AnsiString;  // Declare a new Ansistring
begin
  SetLength(Test, 100000);   // Initialize it to hold 100000 characters
  Test := StringOfChar('X', 100000);  // Fill it with 100000 'X' characters
end;
```

Finally, if you *do* for some unknown reason want to use the old style `ShortString` that is restricted to 255 characters, declare it as such, either using `ShortString` or the old style `String[Size]` declaration:

```
var
  Test: ShortString;  // Declare a new short string of 255 characters
  ShortTest: String[100];  // Also a ShortString of 100 characters
begin
  // This line won't compile, because it's too large for Test
  Test := StringOfChar('X', 100000);  // Fill it with 100000 'X' characters
end;
```

Comment: fpc and objfpc defaults to shortstring. (but using ansistring is possible via {$H+}, and Lazarus templates commonly do this).  Trunk versions support $mode delphiunicode where string=unicodestring, but only the file I/O routines of system and sysutils have adapted till now.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I've edited to include that information. Thanks for letting me know; I've not used FPC for quite some time, and thought they were more close to Delphi in the defaults still.

Comment: They are, if you enable delphi mode ($mode delphi in (every) source or -Sd on the cmdline, the first commonly hidden in central .inc files in the big open source pacakges). But the default mode is mode fpc, which is a cleaned up Turbo Pascal dialect (no 16-bitisms) with some of the more procedural extensions of Delphi. mode objfpc adds classes and most other older Delphi features but has some FPC specific quirks.

Answer (score 6):

In Free Pascal, you do not need to be worry about this. You only need to insert the directive `{$H+}` at the beginning of the source code.

```
{$H+}

var s: String;

begin
    s := StringOfChar('X', 1000);
    writeln(s);
end.
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only solution that has worked for me. I'm testing in replit.com

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`AnsiString` type](http://wiki.freepascal.org/String).